# Resizing matrix getting rid of 0 entries - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have my matrix `E`, which I have been filling in some way (it is not important how, the important thing is that the entries are all different from 0). The dimension of the matrix is `n_x*n_y` X `n_x*n_y`, where

```
n_x = 4
n_y = 8
```

Now I set some of the entries to 0:

```
step = 4.
for i in range(n_x):
    for j in range(n_y):
        if ((i or j)%step != 0):
            e[i][j] = 0.
```

Then I want to get rid of the entries that are equal to 0., resizing my matrix. The way I do that is:

```
filter(lambda a: a != 0., E)
```

but what I get is

```
filter(lambda a: a != 0., E)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can someone explain me what is happening and how to solve it?

EDIT:

I realised I made a mistake in my code, in the part where I am setting to 0 certain entries of my matrix. I will correct this in the following:

```
step = 4.
    for i in range(n_x):
        for j in range(n_y):
            if ((i%step != 0) or (j%step !=0)):
                e[i][j] = 0.
```

Comment: What do you mean by resizing? remove the rows and columns that are fully empty?

Comment: Python version / libraries? Is this just a python list of lists?

Comment: @PaulK. exactly, by resizing I mean removing the entries that are 0. With the modification in my edit, the condition on my matrix guarantees that in any case I always get a new matrix by getting rid of some entries of the original one. The problem is that I don't know how to formally "create" this matrix, from the previous one

Comment: Python version: 2.7.6. Libraries used: essentially only numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted and completed your code a little bit, and it's working fine (see below).

I believe the problem you're seeing is that you are iterating over lists (1 dimension), rather than iterating over the items in the list (2 dimensions / matrix).

You need to `map` your `filter` over the lists that make up your matrix.

```
n_x = 4
n_y = 8
step = 4.

e = [['x' for _ in range(n_y)] for _ in range(n_x)]

# e:
# [['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
#  ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
#  ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
#  ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]



for i in range(n_x):
    for j in range(n_y):
        if ((i or j)%step != 0):
            e[i][j] = 0.

# e: 
# [['x', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'x', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
#  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
#  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
#  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]


# map + filter
no_zeroes = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda a: a != 0., x)), e))

# no_zeroes:
# [['x', 'x'], [], [], []]
```

In case a list comprehension is clearer, this is equivalent:

```
# list comprehensions (equivalent)
no_zeroes_lc = [[col for col in row if col != 0.] for row in e]

# no_zeroes_lc:
# [['x', 'x'], [], [], []]

no_zeroes == no_zeroes_lc  # True
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is what I was looking for, apart from the fact that in no_zeroes (or no_zeroes_lc) I would only like to keep the elements that are actually different from zero, i.e. in your example I would like to have only [['x', 'x']]. Let me also say that I realised I made a mistake in my code (see edit) which is important, because the corrected version guarantees to always have a "matrix" in the end (an object with a fixed number of columns and rows), otherwise not guaranteed a priori. Can you or someone else help me in achieving a shrunk, always non-zero matrix?

Comment: @johnhenry If you have a second question, I believe it's best to write a new question, and not piggy-back on this one. As far as the change in your code, it may have been buggy but I'm get the same intermediate result. I would suggest writing a new question clarifying exactly what you need and explaining your desired input and output matrices clearly.

Comment: Also, I've edited (pending) your question to include `numpy` tag. There is likely a mor optimal numpy solution, but it was unclear in your original question that numpy was available. Be sure to include that type of information.